# NGINX marks some directories as 403 but not others

Tags: php, nginx

I have a PHP app where all requests should get sent to `/dispatch.php`. I'm trying NGINX for the first time, and when I start up my app, the homepage works fine, but when I go to some routes, it works, others it fails. For example, `/systems/` works, but `/login/` doesn't.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www;
    index dispatch.php;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /dispatch.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /dispatch.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass api:9000;
        fastcgi_index dispatch.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fixes timeouts
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the directory path `/var/www/login` exists, but the file `/var/www/login/dispatch.php` does not, then your `try_files` statement will generate a 403 response. Do you have `dispatch.php` files in other directories?

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. No, there is a `dispatch.php` in the root, which controls the entire application. Should I set it to `$document_root/dispatch.php$is_args$args`? Or am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: Try: `try_files $uri /dispatch.php$is_args$args;` in the first location block.